# Access realm object inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, database, asynchronous, android-asynctask, realm

I always get this error when I try to access realm data from an async task:

```
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340): Process: nl.hgrams.passenger, PID: 21340
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at io.realm.BaseRealm.checkIfValid(BaseRealm.java:404)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at io.realm.PSUserActivityMonthRealmProxy.realmGet$weeks(PSUserActivityMonthRealmProxy.java:134)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at nl.hgrams.passenger.model.PSUserActivityMonth.getWeeks(PSUserActivityMonth.java:83)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at nl.hgrams.passenger.activities.PSProfileActivity$8$1.doInBackground(PSProfileActivity.java:361)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
  06-07 16:13:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(21340):  ... 4 more
```

How can I access the data inside AsyncTask? I tried getting the data from the DB again with a realm query call, but I still get this issue

Comment: Please show the the code where you try to access it. That way it is easier for us to guide you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each method that would want to use, there's the Async equivalent, such as :

```
RealmResults<User> result = realm.where(User.class)
                          .equalTo("name", "John")
                          .or()
                          .equalTo("name", "Peter")
                          .findAllAsync();
```

From [their website](https://realm.io/news/realm-java-0.84.0/)